Can't change between multiple Desktop environments using gdm3
I have KDE-plasma and gnome and i'm using gdm3 as a display manager, but it's not letting me switch between the two desktop environments.
Here is the output of neofetch:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64  
Kernel: 6.5.0-41-generic 
Packages: 2739 (dpkg), 15 (flatpak), 15 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 


Are you sure you're selecting a session correctly??  ie. you cannot be logged in and have a session running on the DM, as you use the selection to select a session to start.  Sessions will come from /usr/share/xsessions so those should appear as your choices if you select the correct place. If you've changed the gdm3 theme to one where session choice is hard to see, you may need to change theme to make it easier to pick other sessions.

I had no option for choosing sessions, and i don't remember changing the theme. anyways running 2 DE was causing a lot of problems so i just removed KDE plasma.
